# How do you pass the time in Fallout Classic?

Tags: fallout

In Fallout 3 you could sleep to make time pass. I've hit the first quest in fallout classic and need to come back in the morning.

I've tried going to bed, but it doesn't work.

Is there an easy way to pass time in Fallout?

Answer (score 5):

According to http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Resting
you use the "Pip-Boy 2000 alarm clock function".

Open up your pip boy and on the top left you will see the date and time along with a bell icon. By clicking on the bell, you can choose between several resting/waiting options.

Waiting/resting is also used to heal yourself, as you heal over time, so it is very useful.

As the wiki states, some areas restrict resting though.

Comment: This answer is correct, I belive, but can still be improved upon by adding how to access the alarm clock functionality.